# Python sklearn preprocessing package returns error: ValueError: invalid literal for float()

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

As suggested by another stackoverflow user, I am using sklearn preprocessing package to normalize columns of a pandas dataframe. I create this dataframe from a file which looks like this:

```
0.0 1.0  4.0
0.0 10.0 4.356
```

The following code was working just fine:

```
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x = pd.read_csv("input-file")
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
x= pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
x.to_csv("output-file", sep=" ", index=False, header=False)
```

It is supposed to create a dataframe from a file, normalize the dataframe and save the results to a new file. But out of no where this error showed up and I do not know how to get rid of it:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 364.0
```

I changed the file deleted the extra characters (if there is any like `\n`) but still not working. Any idea why this is happening? Am I missing something?

Thanks

```
pd.read_csv("path")
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform()
messageTrainDf = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
messageTrainDf.to_csv("path", sep=" ", index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Which command generates the error?  Are you using the sklearn MinMaxScaler? sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

Comment: Yes, I am using the MinMaxScaler, just edited the question. The fit_transform line generates the error.

Comment: Did you try specifying the separator explicitly in the `read_csv` call? (e.g., with `sep=r"\s+"`).

Comment: @Alexander the number of columns is just fine

Comment: @MarkDickinson I changed the read_csv part to pd.read_csv("input-file",sep=" ") and it resolved my problem. Thanks. You may want to post it as answer.

Comment: Always include relevant parts of stack trace with the error message - it's impossible to tell what code triggers it otherwise.